# Login / Password for Oracle Enterprise Manager in VM template?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-enterprise-manager

**I want to setup Oracle Enterprise Manager to access our development Oracle databases.**

I downloaded the following VM template from https://edelivery.oracle.com/EPD/Search/handle_go

`Oracle VM VirtualBox for Oracle Enterprise Manager Cloud Control 12c Release 3 (12.1.0.3) Media Pack for x86 (64 bit)`

I unzipped the OVA files, merged them and imported them into Oracle Virtualbox.

Then I started up the VM, logged into Sqlplus and changed the password of SYSMAN and unlocked that account. Then I pointed Firefox (inside the VM) to https://emcc.example.com:7799/em , where the Login screen of Enterprise Manager was shown.

However, I cannot log in to Enterprise Manager. I tried it with the following usernames/passwords:

- SYSMAN / [the new SYSMAN password I entered before]
- oracle / welcome1 (the Linux account)
- cloudadm / cloud (these are credentials I found on the web)

It always says `Authentication failed. If problem persists, contact your system administrator.`

**What are the credentials to log into Enterprise Manager in these VM templates by Oracle?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Readme for each Oracle Template download. Here is the related part from the Readme for your template:

```
5. O/S passwords: The passwords for the "root" and "oracle" O/S users are "welcome1"

6. All Enterprise Manager Cloud Control passwords are "welcome1"
```

[image]

Comment: Where did you find this Readme? The Readme in `/home/oracle` did not contain such info.

Comment: It's on the download page, not inside the VM, added the picture.